# Python, simple example of multiple variables passed to another function

Tags: python, function, variables

I know this has been explained here before, but I still cannot figure it out for my scenario, which I explain as simple as this:

```
def func1 ():
  a = 1
  b = 2
  print a + b

def func2 ():
  c = 3
  d = 4
  e = a * c
  f = b + d

func1()
func2()
```

When run like this:

```
$ ./test1.py 
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test1.py", line 18, in <module>
    func2()
  File "./test1.py", line 14, in func2
    e = a * c
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Simple question is, how to change above code so func2 stores variables from func1?

Comment: Have a read of http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html and possibly the earlier chapters too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this is with `return` and parameters.

```
def func1 ():
  a = 1
  b = 2
  return a,b

def func2 (a, b):
  c = 3
  d = 4
  e = a * c
  f = b + d

a, b = func1()
print(a, b)
func2(a, b)
```

Result:

```
>>> a, b = func1()
>>> print(a, b)
1 2
>>> func2(a, b)
```

Comment: I lost some reputation points on this question, but I've learnt something here! Just realized that your solution allows me to add a third argument as both variables are "exported" from the func1, unlike as solution from Ewan who uses unpacking with wildcards, but that can have some easy solution as well, not sure.

Comment: That's not a wildcard; it's a special operator that (in this context) unpacks an iterable. It will unpack everything automatically, handling two arguments just as easily as three [or more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters). You just have to make sure the arguments you're providing match the other function's parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than make the variables global as mentioned in the other answers, I would return them in `func1` and consume them in `func2`.

```
def func1():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    print a + b
    return a, b

def func2(a, b):
    c = 3
    d = 4
    e = a * c
    f = b + d

func2(*func1())
```

As we are returning multiple variables in `func1()` these come as a tuple `(a, b)`.

Rather than pass this as a single variable to `func2` we must *unpack* them into 2 variables.

Here is an excellent [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python) on the subject of `*args` `**kwargs`.

Comment: That is what I was looking for! I missed the crutial part, returning variables on the end of the function. Can I ask what that asterix does in func2(*func1())?

Comment: @Viktor - updated my answer and linked to a much better explanation to help you

Comment: thanks a lot. One more problem. if I define third variable that does not come from func1, eg. func2 (a, b, g): and call it based on your code, func2(*func1(), 5), I get error: SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression.

Comment: @Viktor - it's not a wildcard (looking at your comment on the other answer). If you wanted to add more arguments you just add them before the unpacking. e.g. `func2(g, a, b)` and `func2(5,*func1())`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1
b = 2
def func1 ():
    print a + b

def func2 ():
    c = 3
    d = 4
    e = a * c
    f = b + d

func1()
func2()
```

Comment: sorry, variables (a and b) must be defined inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just made the variable global (without this, a and b are only local variables):

```
def func1 ():
  global a, b
  a = 1
  b = 2
  print a + b

def func2 ():
  c = 3
  d = 4
  e = a * c
  f = b + d

func1()
func2()
```

But better avoid this solution

Comment: Note that although this answer is correct, what OP wants to do is generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: @Kupiakos: Yes! Avoiding adding lot of name in global dictionary… But sometimes… Well put in the answer:-) Thanks

Comment: @Viktor: So I've noticed it (thanks Kupiakos to remember me this!!)